# SNMP Library for Java

Tags: java, libraries, snmp, snmp4j

I need to make a feasibility study on various SNMP libraries. Currently I am using SNMP4J. My requirement is to compare various libraries with their features. I wasn't able to locate any useful reference links.
Please someone suggest any links.

Comment: Then I suggest you perform your own research by evaluating existing libraries, unless you can wait till someone does that some day.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For a list of SNMP frameworks for java, see [SNMPLink.org](http://www.snmplink.org/software/fordeveloper/#8)

In my experience, for an open source, [SNMP4J](http://www.agentpp.com/api/java/snmp4j.html) is the leader.

For a real compare you must **try** each one of them (not only reading) and see:
1. Easy and intuitive usage
2. You can accomplish all task you wish
3. Mark a special concept of the framework (if exists)
4. No-bugs
5. Performance
6. A live community

Other frameworks:

- [WebNMS](http://www.webnms.com/javaagent/index.html) - commerical
- [DynamicSNMP](http://www.monfox.com/dsnmp/java-snmp-agent-sdk.html)
- [NetSNMPJ](http://netsnmpj.sourceforge.net/)

Good luck and let us know of your results.