# How to use SNMP with Java?

Tags: java, snmp

I'm writing an application that accesses a network printer. As a part of that application, I need to know the "status" of the printer. The only way the printer advertises its status is through SNMP. Java itself doesn't have any tools that speak the SNMP protocol, so I'm not sure what to do. How can I access the printer's SNMP status updates from a Java application?

Comment: Try SNMP4j. www.snmp4j.org

Comment: @ prasanth Many thanks. I'm looking some examples. I have limited time to finises this.

Comment: Try this example. Follow the instructions given there. http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/snmp/create-snmp-client-in-java-using-snmp4j/

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817554